# 'Animating' movement in Processing.py

Tags: python, processing

I need to animate the movement of some linkages in `processing`. I use `processing.py`

I tried a toy example where I move a line segment across the screen.  My idea was to:
1) draw the line
2) delay for a second
3) erase the screen
4) change the location of the line
5) repeat.

But my code doesn't work.  It increments through, but ultimately only shows the final line location. I never see the intermediate step lines.

```
import math

def setup():
    size(800, 500)
    noLoop()

def draw():

    line(100,100,200,200)
    delay(100)

    x1,y1,x2,y2 = (100,100,200,200)

    for chunk in range(10,100,10):
        print(chunk)
        background(255)
        line(x1,y1,x2,y2)
        delay(1000)
        x2 += chunk
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the documentation of [`draw()`](https://processing.org/reference/draw_.html):

> [...] All Processing programs update the screen at the end of `draw()`, never earlier.

In processing `draw()` is executed continuously, thus you do not need a loop. Increment `x2` in `draw` and control the frames per second by [`frameRate`](https://processing.org/reference/frameRate_.html)

```py
x1,y1,x2,y2 = (100,100,200,200)
chunk = 10

def setup():
    size(800, 500)
    frameRate(10)

def draw():
    global x2

    background(255)
    line(x1,y1,x2,y2)
    x2 += chunk
```